# As a software developer what is your SNMP suite that easy to integrate into your software

Tags: c++, python, c, linux, snmp

Well, altough the **S** of the **SNMP** stands for **S**imple, yet, so far I haven't experienced it that way. And now that I am about to deploy my software on around around 180 remote Linux servers and wants to monitor the servers and configure my daemons all from a centralized point.

I simply want you to recommend me the library which you'll confidently describe as "SNMP Made Easy".

I am looking for a suite of software which not standing in the developer's way, easy to work with (install, configure).

Speaking from the NOC perspective, the ideal would be such one which requires no maintenance once installed.

**Note: Open Source is mandatory**.

Comment: 'Tis "simple" as in "this protocol is a simpleton" or "this protocol is simple to implement on a Z-80 which is spending most of its time routing packets when we don't even yet know what information we want it to give". Contrast with "easy to use", "expressive", "does not need big wrapper to be useful". It was a great protocol for 1990, alas, unlike Kermit, it will probably outlive you and me.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't describe it as *easy*, but the *easiest* I've found (quite a while ago) was [pysnmp](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/) -- I had to wrap it with a couple of façades to make it somewhat usable by people who weren't deep SNMP experts (and that code I had to leave behind at a previous employer, was never open-sourced, and I couldn't reconstruct it right now but would have to develop again from scratch).  However, so many years have passed (with PySNMP in continuous development, now with a PSF grant too) that it may definitely have gotten better (one can hope;-).

Comment: Pysnmp now has a high level interface so that you can do SNMP queries in a single call, both synchronously and asynchronously.  See http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/4.x/index.html#ONELINER-APPS

Comment: @Dave, tx for the update -- I'm sure that makes it much easier to use (the "single-call queries" sync and async were roughly the facades I had made, but mine had rough edges and limitations, due to time pressure;-).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Net-SNMP](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/) . It has BSD licence. If you are open for java [snmp4j](http://www.snmp4j.org/) is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I am still searching for that easy to use suite of SNMP tools/API myself.

I build OA&M and I've tried NET-SNMP, Windows SNMP and lately agentpp (www.agentpp.com). 
Personally, I preferred the agentpp.

Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

The "S" in SNMP is actually for "simple" not because using it is simple, but rather because the protocol (on the wire) is designed to be simple and easy to implement.  And it is.  Now...  actually implementing it and then **using** it is where the S completely drops away.